# jquery removeClass does not work

Tags: jquery

pls consider the following simplified code which is supposed to SHOW the div element, but it doesn't. I checked this site and the jquery site (http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) but cant figure out why removeClass is not working in my code???

Pls your help...

code:

```
<head>
<style>
.hideElement {display:none;}
</style>


</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>        

<body>
<h2>Products </h2>

<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">

    <div class="hideElement" id="product1"> Product X </div>

<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Submit Form">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#product1").removeClass('hideElement');

}
)

</script>
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you see anything in the error console?

Comment: Working fine ..http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1390/

Comment: Can't see any problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sJcYJ/

Comment: most interesting that it works in your case (??). The error is that the "Product X" text (in div product1) does not show when I load the html file in my browser. In the console I get the errors: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility here for the issue of your jquery file `path`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

To test it ,try with

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
                     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
```

otherwise [everything working fine in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1390/).

Comment: thnx (!). You were right about the path, e.g. I used your suggestion. Though I still havent figured out why my path (/js/...) does not work as I used it before with success...Will dig a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as is:
http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/KdFYY/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#product1").removeClass('hideElement');

}
)
```

Is JQuery loading properly? Check your path.